# WPF :: DataContext Is throwing "Not Set To An Instance" When Pointing to a STATIC class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datacontext

I am following the guidance in [this Microsoft post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf/archive/2010/08/04/bind-my-ribbon-ui-to-my-data-model.aspx) for setting up `Ribbon` controls with static properties as their `DataContext` to bind the UI to a datamodel.

The relevant XAML looks like so:

```
<Ribbon>
  <RibbonGroup Header="Group1">
    <RibbonToggleButton DataContext="{x:Static vm:WordModel.Bold}"/>
  </RibbonGroup>
</Ribbon>
```

... and the class for the `DataContext`:

```
public static class WordModel
{
  private static readonly object LockObject = new object();
  private static readonly Dictionary<string, ControlData> _dataCollection = 
     new Dictionary<string, ControlData>();

  public static ControlData Bold
  {
     get
     {
        lock (LockObject)
        {
           const string key = "Bold";
           if (!_dataCollection.ContainsKey(key))
           {
              var data = new ToggleButtonData()
              {
                 Command = EditingCommands.ToggleBold,
                 IsChecked = false,
                 KeyTip = "B",
                 SmallImage = Application.Current.Resources["BoldIcon"] as DrawingImage,
                 ToolTipDescription = "Toggles the Bold font weight on the current selection.",
                 ToolTipTitle = "Bold (Ctrl + B)",
              };
              _dataCollection[key] = data;
           }
           return _dataCollection[key];
        }
     }
  }
}
```

... which is a ***static*** class and property.  Why would the compiler be giving me the blue squiggly and grousing about "`Object reference not set to an instance of an object`"?  I am setting the DataContext to point to a *static* reference with the `{x:Static ...}` bit, am I not?

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here, but darned if I know what it is.

Comment: Sure that the property getter doesn't throw that exception?

Comment: Did you initialize `LockObject` and `_dataCollection`?  If you catch the `NullReferenceException` when it is thrown, from where is it thrown?

Comment: also `SmallImage`  is a Uri, or at least was in the original sample

Comment: the problem was the SmallImage setter - I was checking _smallImage.Equals(value) when _smallImage was *null*.  I'll give this post a couple of hours and delete the evidence of my stupidity.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the "thou shouldst reconsider deleting answered questions" recommendation, I'm posting the answer here and accepting my shame publicly.  :-)

The problem was in the setter of SmallImage:

```
  private ImageSource _smallImage ;
  public ImageSource SmallImage
  {
     get
     {
        return _smallImage;
     }

     set
     {
        if (_smallImage.Equals(value)) return;
        _smallImage = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(() => SmallImage);
     }
  }
```

_smallImage was initially `null`, just as you'd expect, and `null.Equals(value)` doesn't work well, obviously.  I changed that line to

```
if (_smallImage == value) return;
```

and all is well with the world.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a design time error.

Whenever the designer accesses things in design time, the constructor and properties of the object within the process flow may be touched. If you don't care to resolve the items for it during that time, put in the check to work around it in design time.

WPF

```
if (!DesignerProperties.IsInDesignModeProperty)
```

Silverlight

```
if (!DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool)
```

Comment: Sadly, it wasn't that - it was my own stupidity.  See the answer above.  :-)